# Why is the weird ' usage for ns/use with Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I define namespace inside a clojure lib without ',

```
(ns myproject.hello)
```

But, I use ' for using it.

```
(use 'myproject.hello)
```

Why is this? Is there any logic behind this? In gosh (dialect of scheme), I use without ' i.e. (use myproject) Why is this irregularity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: `ns` is a macro, so its arguments are not evaluated.  `use` is a function, so its arguments must be quoted to prevent the compiler from evaluating them.

The use/require functions were not part of the original design of Clojure, they got added by contributors.  They are in need of an overhaul.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way is:

(ns myproject.hello

(:use myproject.world))

Comment: Could you explain why this is idiomatic, and what the difference is between `use` and putting `:use` inside `ns`?

Comment: They have pretty much the same effect. However it's easier for both readers of code and automated tools to look at the ns declaration to work out what is being included, so it makes sense for that to be the idiomatic approach.